# Why doesn't my React component renders what I want in a foreach, but will console.log the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach

I'm following an online course about React, and I'm practicing with an API ( swapi.co ). The goal is to play around with the API and make a React app that does whatever we want with it.

So I'm trying to make an app that has an input, and everytime the input changes, it fetches the matching character through the API and displays data about the character. One of the data is the name of the films the character was in, so it's an array containing one or many strings. Everything goes well until I try to loop through that array to display. It will console.log the whole array, but won't loop through it with foreach.

Here's my result component :

```
class ResultPeople extends Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        movieTitles: []
    }
}
getMovies(movies) {
    var movieTitleList = [];
    movies.forEach(element => {
        fetch(element)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(movieData => {
            movieTitleList.push(movieData.title);
        })
    });
    this.setState({movieTitles: movieTitleList});
    console.log('getMovies Done');
}
render() {
    const { resultdata } = this.props;
    const { name, films } = resultdata;
    return (
        <div className="result-characters text-white">
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            {films ? <button onClick={() => this.getMovies(films)}>See movies</button> : ''}
            {
                this.state.movieTitles ? <MovieList movies={this.state.movieTitles} /> : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

And here's the movie list :

```
const MovieList = ({ movies }) => {
return (
    <ul>
        {console.log(movies)}
        {
            movies.forEach(element => {
                return <li>{element}</li>;
            })
        }
    </ul>
);
```

}

I have no clue as to why it behaves that way. console.log(movies) works well ( though depending on the times it logs a different amount of films, perhaps because of the API ? ). But the foreach doesn't.

Where's the mistake here ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a series of async calls that return promises, and you need to wait for all of them to finish before setting the state.

Iterate the movies with `Array.map()` make the fetch calls, and return the promises. Wait for all promises to finish using `Promise.all()`, and then set the state.

Example (not tested):

```
getMovies(movies) {
  Promise.all(movies.map(element =>
    fetch(element)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(movieData => movieData.title)
  )).then(movieTitles => this.setState({ movieTitles }))
}
```

Use `Array.map()` in your component as well, since you can return from `Array.forEach()`.

**Note:** the `key` should be unique. In this example, I use the element itself, but if they're not unique, you'll need to generate a unique key.

```
const MovieList = ({ movies }) => (
  <ul>
  {
    movies.map(element => (
      <li key={element}>{element}</li>;
    ))
  }
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: I did what you said, now the results are consistent and I seem to get the proper array more often, but should that solve the foreach issue ?

Comment: Updated with the component as well. You can't return from `Array.forEach()`, it's built for side effects, and not to transform an array to another array. This is done with `Array.map()`.

Comment: It's fine, thanks a lot it's working great now ! One question though about the getMovies part. I'm having troubles understanding it. Am I mistaking if I say understand that Promise.all(...) provides the setState line with an array containing the movies ? If so, how is the array created ? Is it just being created with the "movieData => movieData.title" line ?

Comment: Each promise waits for the fetch to return, and then resolved with the movie's title. When the array of promises is resolved, `Promise.all()` is resolved with all the promises values (the titles), and you get an array of titles. You should read more about fetch, and promises.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake (I also trapped into it several times) - use .map!

I mean there is forEach in MovieList component.

Also you have initial movieTitles: [] array, and `this.state.movieTitles ?` check will be always true.
Setting null or removing this check is ok.

Comment: Thanks ! I indeed used a .map instead, and it's working well. Why's that ? ( I also removed the check, it's working too )

Comment: forEach will return undefined, and React is expecting array or single component or at least null.

Answer (score 0):

The call you are making in the foreach loop is async while the function itself is synchronous. I would probably write it as a map function that returns a set of promises that when resolved sets the state.

```
...
async getMovies(movies) {
    const promises = movies.map(async (element) => {
        const response = await fetch(element)
        const json = await response.json()

        return json.title
    })

    const titles = await Promise.all(promises)

    this.setState({movieTitles: titles});
}
...
```

The async / await is just a shorter form, you can accomplish the same with then / catch. I would also add some more exception handling and possibly return a falsy value when it fails to filter out the invalid movie titles.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Array.prototype.map()` not `Array.prototype.forEach()`

> > map() returns a new array based on the callback you provide (which is what you want)

`{movies.map(element => (<li>{element}</li>)}`

> > forEach() runs the code in the callback, but then returns undefined.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I used a .map() instead, thanks, but how is it returning another array ? It's just returning a JSX element

Comment: What map does is iterate through the first array and returns to a new array of whatever you return from the callback. You could assign it to a variable, which would contain the array, but here you are rendering each element instead.